# Does a motherboard/BIOS store a reason for why it shut itself down?

Tags: computer-building

I'm diagnosing an issue where the motherboard appears to be shutting down my custom build. I'd like to figure out the root cause more simply than trial and error with components.

While I realize that these are hardware faults, I know the line between hardware and software can be pretty blurred. I'm curious if there's anything that centrally logs or stores a reason code for motherboards generally as to why it shutdown? Does the BIOS or anything else log the reason a shutdown was triggered?

Comment: Often there's a error message on the bios screen. I accidentally shorted out my PSU, causing my motherboard to shut down a few times. Stuff like this is *massively* manufacturer specific tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never seen that sort of feature on any consumer grade system at the mainboard level, it comes down to expense and how often such a feature would be used. The vast majority of consumers wouldn't use (or want) such a feature which would increase the cost of manufacture. The vast majority of consumers wouldn't pay extra for a feature that they'd possibly never use and manufacturers wouldn't add something that there competitors wouldn't - they'd have to increase the price or absorb the cost.

In server class systems they often have other boards that provide such a facility - logging power cycles, alerts on environmental conditions, hardware PFA's etc. The IBM System X series had RSA cards that provided these features as well as remote control facilities via a web interface.